# Call Interface function from main class from sub object

Tags: java, android, service

Solution: 
The following worked fine, but I had two Activities already using my helper class, but forgot to add the Interface to one Activity.
So I got the TypeCastException.
But I did not realize I always looked at the wrong Activity, so I could not find the issue.

---

I currently write my first android service, which works fine.

Now I realized, that I have to bind unbind, check binding all over and so I thought to put all into a subclass and only do an interface with callbacks for the only functions I need.

But now i am stuck to call my interface functions
onTcBlueServiceConnected()
onTcBlueServiceDisconnected()

I simply want to prevent to write the same code over and over again.

Each activity I have to use the service, I extend from this helper class, instead of the AppCompatActivity.

Maybe I chose the wrong path, but lost with the right words for a search.

As far as I understand bound services, I have to bind from each activity I access the service, and unbind of course when it is destroyed.

So I thought this is a good approach

```
public abstract class TcBlueServiceHelper extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String LOG_TAG = "TcBlueServiceHelper";
    TcBlueService mTcBlueService;
    TcBlueService.TcBlueBinder myBinder;
    boolean mServiceBound = false;

    Context mCallingContext;


    public TcBlueServiceHelper(Context callingContext) {
        mCallingContext = callingContext;
    }

    public TcBlueServiceHelper(){
        mCallingContext = this;
    }

    public void bindServiceSave(){
        if (mServiceBound == false) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TcBlueService.class);
            startService(intent);
            bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

    }

    public void unbindServiceSave(){
        if (mServiceBound) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mServiceBound = false;
        }
    }

    public TcBlueService.TcBlueBinder getBinder(){
        return myBinder;
    }



    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServiceBound = false;
            ((ITcBlueServiceHelper)mCallingContext).onTCBServiceDisconnected(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            myBinder = (TcBlueService.TcBlueBinder) service;
            mTcBlueService = myBinder.getService();
            mServiceBound = true;

            ((ITcBlueServiceHelper)mCallingContext).onTCBServiceConnected(name, service);
        }
    };
    public interface ITcBlueServiceHelper{
        public void onTCBServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service);
        public void onTCBServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name);
    }
}
```

My first thought to cast result in a "ClassCastException"

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: de.mobacomp.android.freightweight.StartActivity cannot be cast to de.mobacomp.android.freightweight.TcBlueServiceHelper$ITcBlueServiceHelper
                      at de.mobacomp.android.freightweight.TcBlueServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(TcBlueServiceHelper.java:72)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: does your `de.mobacomp.android.freightweight.StartActivity` class implement `ITcBlueServiceHelper`?

Comment: You are the hero of my day.